#  Kahler forms on Cohen Macaulay spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Hi.

Can anyone answer the two following questions:

> 1. For $n$-dimensional $X$ Cohen-Macaulay complex space, is it true that the sheaf of top degree homolorphic forms $\Omega^{n}_{X}$ has no torsion?
> 2. For $f:X\rightarrow S$ Cohen-Macaulay morphism of reduced complex spaces, is it true that  $\Omega^{n}_{X/S}$ has no torsion on $X$?

I think that these two questions have negative answers; but I don't know how to prove it.

In fact, if it is true then the "fundamental class morphism" would be injective!

Thank you.

Comment: The answer to (1) is definitely "no" since there is always a nowhere-dense analytic set on whose complement the space $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay. One gets similarly many counterexamples to (2) beginning with any flat analytic map $f$. 

Comment: Dear Mohamed: please try to not post duplicate questions.  As it stands, one of yours got -1 and the other +1 (who knows what's up with that).  

Comment: @BCnrd: I don't understand the relevance of the existence of an open dense Cohen-Macaulay subset. In any case it is easy to give an example: Consider the union of the coordinate axes in the plane, $xy=0$. Then we have the only relation $xdy+ydx=0$ so that that $xdy$ is a non-zero torsion element (killed by $x$ and $y$).

Comment: @Torsten: I was just pointing out that it should be ubiquitous that the requested condition fails, such as any situation where the sheaf is not torsion-free over the complement of a nowhere-dense analytic set (I was thinking of $X$ which is not generically reduced).  

Comment: @BCnrd: Got you. A non-reduced counterexample is of course not cheating yet it somehow feels like it....

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Brian and Ekedahl.

Yes, in any case the answer is "NO"; After asking the question, I made some easy computation with the Whitney umbrella $\lbrace{(x,y,z)\in {\Bbb C}^{3}: x^{2}-zy^{2}=0}\rbrace$ which convinces me that 1) is not true.

For the second question, see Kunz-Waldi, Contem.Math 79 \$.5; the kernel of the relative fundamental class is almost never empty...

P.S: Excuse me, I don't know how to add some comment to the question.

Comment: If one takes a reduced irreducible curve (hence Cohen-Macaulay), most of the time (and easy to check), the module of 1-forms will have torsion. In fact, a well known conjecture of Berger posits that if this module is torsion free then the curve is smooth. The conjecture is open to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Hi Mohan, nice to see you here !

Comment: kaddar, you should accept this answer by clicking the checkmark to the left, if you're satisfied by this.  That way the question will be marked as answered in the system.